# Schedule WSUS Updates for a group of devices

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-update

Is it possible to configure wsus to schedule updates for different groups of devices? I have a group of devices that requires updates on a specific day compared to the rest of the devices that receive as and when.

Tried using GPO against the OU of the devices (Image attached) but the devices are still installing updates during active hours. At the moment, the device go straight out to the web to get the updates but unsure if WSUS can schedule them instead.

[GPO Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vi7i.png)